# How to build a property grid in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, ide

I am building an IDE type application in `Angular 6` specific to my domain where I need to allow the user to edit properties of C# objects. Think of the Visual Studio property grid for a Windows Forms or Web Forms project where you can click on a button on the form and in the property grid you can change the properties of the button (e.g. color,size,text,etc).

I had the idea of sending a `json` string to the client that includes the properties of the object with their current values. Something like this:

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"Volume",
"type":"VolumeCalculator",
"properties":
[
  {
    "name":"NumberOfLevels",
    "type":"int",
    "value":2
  },
  {
    "name":"Period",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":
    [
      {
        "name":"From",
        "type":"DateTime",
        "properties":
        [
          {
            "name":"FromDate",
            "type":"Date",
            "value":"01/01/2018"
          },
          {
            "name":"FromTime",
            "type":"Time",
            "value":"12:00:00"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"Until",
        "type":"DateTime",
        "value":"02/01/2018 12:00:00"
      }         
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"TreeType",
    "type":"enum",
    "value":2,
    "options":["Path Graph","Star Like"]
  }
]
}
```

With this `json` string I have all the information I need to build a `grid`. Different data types will present different editors. A `DateTime` type would allow the user to click a calendar icon to bring up a calendar and choose a value. An `Enum` type would present a drop down where the user would pick from the provided values.

Where I am struggling is I am relatively new to `Angular 6` development. I have built some simpler applications so I am familiar with beginner level `Angular` concepts. I think this problem requires a bit more advanced concepts that I am just unfamiliar with so am looking for pointers. Perhaps this should be a directive? Perhaps it is just a component itself and no directive is necessary.

I am not asking for a complete solution (however, if someone wants to provide one I won't complain), just some direction from the `Angular` experts.

I am even interested in just buying a library that already provides the functionality, but so far I have been unable to find one that supports `Angular 6`. If anyone knows of one, I am happy to review it to see if it will work for me.

Comment: See source code https://github.com/mokeyish/ngx-property-grid